# EWS API - Create calendar and share with reviewer permissions

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm having some trouble on **creating and share a calendar with review permissions using Exchange Webservice API .NET**.

At the moment this is my code:

```
Folder addCalendar = new Folder(service);
addCalendar.DisplayName = name;
addCalendar.FolderClass = "IPF.Appointment";
var perm = new FolderPermission(new UserId("reviewer@test.com"),
                            FolderPermissionLevel.Reviewer);
addCalendar.Permissions.Add(perm);
addCalendar.Save(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
```

The calendar is created, in my account I can see the calendar and the user 'reviewer@test.com' has the correct permissions.

The problem is: **The calendar doesn't show at the reviewer's account.**

Comment: What do you mean with "Doesn't show at the reviewer's account"? Can the reviewer open the calendar using Outlook? File -> Open -> Other users Folder.

Comment: Well I tried with the reviewer account open his calendar and I didn't succeed, but anyway I wanted to share the calendar with the EWS API without the need of using outlook to complete the process.

Comment: Do I unerstand you correctly that you want to create a sharing invitation message? The one which Outlook creates when you right click on your calendar and select Share -> Share calendar?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I want to do!

Answer (score 4):

You have to do two things:

Set the appropiate permissions:

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
folder.Permissions.Add(new FolderPermission("someone@yourcompany.com", 
    FolderPermissionLevel.Reviewer));
folder.Update();
```

Then, send an invitation message. Now, this is the hard part. The message format is specifified in [[MS-OXSHARE]: Sharing Message Object Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433485(v=EXCHG.80).aspx). The extended properties are defined in [[MS-OXPROPS]: Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433490(v=exchg.80).aspx). You need to create a message according to that specification and send it to the recipient.

EDITED:

To set the sharing properties on the element, use extended properties.

First, define the properties. For example, the PidLidSharingProviderGuidProperty is defined as follows:

```
private static readonly Guid PropertySetSharing = new Guid("{00062040-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
private static readonly ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidSharingProviderGuidProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PropertySetSharing, 0x8A01, MapiPropertyType.CLSID);      
private static readonly ExtendedPropertyDefinition ConversationIdProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3013, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
```

You can then set the property on a new item using the SetExtendedProperty method:

```
item.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidSharingProviderGuidProperty, "somevalue");
```

Comment: How do I get this kind of values: PidNameXSharingProviderGuid, PidLidSharingFlavor, PidNameXSharingFlavor, PidLidSharingCapabilities, PidNameXSharingCapabilities, etc.?

Comment: Added an example on how to set the properties on an item.

Comment: And where should I see what those "somevalues" must be? :/

Comment: Well, that is specified in the specification I wrote about in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to programmatically send a sharing invitation within an organization through EWS.  May not answer all your questions, but it's a good start to understanding how in-depth you gotta get to actually do it. [Heres the link](http://willcode4foodblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/understanding-sharing-invitation-requests-ews-managed-api-1-2-part-1/)